# Error in picking the latest event

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have table in the DB say MyHistory table. Based on event history , I have to pick latest event in my events say LOGIN and SUPPORT. I have to pick whatever the event performed latest.

Note : Event does not have priority that particulate event has to perform order.

While running the below code , I got the error like

ERROR: error - too many values to unpack

What is the wrong in the below code?

def my_welcome_msg(self):

```
    msg_created_date = MyHistory.objects.select_related().filter(
        cluster=self.cluster).filter(
        event_type=MyHistory.SUPPORT).filter(MyHistory.LOGIN).order_by('created_date')[0].created_date
    return msg_created_date
```

I have records related to single user_id in a table as shown below.

| id |created_date|modified_date| description |user_id | event_type | cluster_id

1   2017-05-31 01:00:58                                  SUPPORT

2    2017-05-30 23:00:38                                  LOGIN

Answer (score 1):

There're several problems with your code. Firstly, Django doesn't support empty `select_related` for a long time, you're either using a very outdated Django version or should explicitly list all related models to fetch. Secondly, your code tries to fetch `MyHistory` objects that has mutually exclusive types. Thirdly, your code is ordering by date in the wrong order.

```
last_msg = (MyHistory.objects
            .filter(cluster=self.cluster)
            .filter(event_type__in=[MyHistory.SUPPORT, MyHistory.LOGIN])
            .order_by('-created_date').first())
return last_msg.created_date if last_msg else None
```

Comment: When I tried your code , got an error r - unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: @AnilKumarThotamalla Please, provide a full traceback for your error also models definition. It is clear that my code doesn't contain any date arithmetic, so it can't generate such an error.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't mean that your code. I have taken your sample code and implemented in my code. So I got the error.

Comment: @AnilKumarThotamalla it is impossible to figure out what is causing the error without seeing: 1) your model definition 2) full exception traceback 3) actual code where the error happened

Comment: def my_welcome_msg(self):
        msg_created_date = (MyHistory.objects.filter(cluster=self.cluster).filter(event_type=[MyHistory.SUPPORT,MyHistory.LOGIN]).order_by('-created_date').first())
        return msg_created_date

Comment: @AnilKumarThotamalla You just reposted my code which is already available in the answer and does not provide any new information. You should also check the return value, as it is clear from the code that if no `MyHistory` object is found, then the caller will get `None` value.

Comment: def my_welcome_msg(self):
        msg_created_date = (MyHistory.objects.filter(cluster=self.cluster).filter(event_type=[MyHistory.SUPPORT,MyHistory.LOGIN]).order_by('-created_date').first())
        return msg_created_date.created_date if msg_created_date else None   ERROR: Error:  error - unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'